# pandas function to fill missing values from other dataframe based on matching column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have two dataframes: one where certain columns are filled in and one where others are filled in but some from the previous df are missing. Both share some common non-empty columns.

```
DF1:
FirstName Uid JoinDate BirthDate
      Bob   1 20160628       NaN
  Charlie   3 20160627       NaN

DF2:
FirstName Uid JoinDate BirthDate
      Bob   1      NaN  19910524
    Alice   2      NaN  19950403

Result:
FirstName Uid JoinDate BirthDate
      Bob   1 20160628  19910524
    Alice   2      NaN  19950403
  Charlie   3 20160627       NaN
```

Assuming that these rows do not share index positions in their respective dataframes, is there a way that I can fill the missing values in DF1 with values from DF2 where the rows match on a certain column (in this example Uid)?

Also, is there a way to create a new entry in DF1 from DF2 if there isn't a match on that column (e.g. Uid) without removing rows in DF1 that don't match any rows in DF2?

EDIT: I updated the dataframes to add non-matching results in both dataframes that I need in the result df. I also updated my last question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** you can do it setting the proper indices and finally resetting the index of joined DF:

```
In [14]: df1.set_index('FirstName').combine_first(df2.set_index('FirstName')).reset_index()
Out[14]:
  FirstName  Uid    JoinDate   BirthDate
0     Alice  2.0         NaN  19950403.0
1       Bob  1.0  20160628.0  19910524.0
2   Charlie  3.0  20160627.0         NaN
```

try this:

```
In [113]: df2.combine_first(df1)
Out[113]:
  FirstName  Uid    JoinDate  BirthDate
0       Bob    1  20160628.0   19910524
1     Alice    2         NaN   19950403
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I'm looking for, however if there is a row in DF1 that doesn't match any rows in DF2, they get eliminated. I've updated my original question to better reflect what I'm looking for.

Comment: perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for!